# Continually, different Linux distros keep freezing while windows 10 working fine

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, tails-os

I have been trying different Gnu/Linux distros like Ubuntu, Tails, and now Kali, and with all of them I've had the same problem, they keep freezing, itt doesn't freeze forever, sometimes only the window I'm using stops responding, other times the whole screen just freezes, while this happens the mouse works, but no clicks are registered, and sound still works when playing videos.

I have a dell Inspiron 14 3467 with an intel i5 7200. It runs Windows 10 flawlessly, so I don't understand why it would be different for Linux, and Linux is even lighter.

I tried to find the problem by checking the task manager, and normally Firefox takes 20% of the CPU, there is no problem there. What was strange was that the task manager was using around 20% or even more. I close it to see if it made any difference when working but it did nothing.

So to conclude, I have no idea what the problem could be.

Ps. Even sometimes the terminal wouldn't open for some reason :(

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what happens when the computer "freezes"? Is this temporary, or is a reboot required? How much memory does the system has? Is there anything of interest in the system logs?

Comment: it freezes for around a minute or two. And my laptop has 8gb or ram and a 1 tb hdd

Comment: And I cant use really click on anything else for that two minutes

Comment: Might be a GPU problem, could you specify?

Comment: I don't mean it couldn't, because it certainly can be, but if it works completely fine on windows 10 then I don't see the relationship

Comment: It has happened with the three different linux distros I have tried

Comment: **Edit you question** to explain what you mean by freezes: Does if freeze forever, is it just one window that freezes, can you move windows or the mouse, does sound stop, …?

Comment: What about running any of the tools like `sa`, `sysstat`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, etc., and then presenting the output when the problem had occurred?

Answer (score 2):

With the little information we have, I think there are three main possibilities for what could be going wrong here:

1. You have a hardware problem that Linux happens to hit but Windows doesn't. This happens sometimes.
2. There's a GPU bug. What graphics card and graphics driver do you have?
3. Something's eating a lot of memory and you're hitting swap and it's killing performance while that thrashes.

I'd start at the bottom here: run a process monitor that shows memory usage and IO and watch what happens when you experience the problem.

You should also look at the system logs to see if there's anything of interest. You can run `sudo journalctl -f -pwarning` in a terminal to get a stream of current log entries of severity warning or higher. Change to `sudo journalctl -b -pwarning` to get a log of all such messages since last boot.